# jQuery checkbox control from HTML AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have been searching this site for a few days now but haven't managed to find the exact answer I'm after. I am relatively new to this so please bear with me!

I have a HTML page that performs an AJAX request to the web server every second, the response returns two values for two check boxes. The server maintains the current state of the check boxes at all times.

Its based on an example online and works perfectly.

I have incorporated the jQuery script such that the web page had a phone friendly GUI, the functions of the check boxes work perfectly, however I cannot set the jQuery check boxes from the HTML code that handles the AJAX response.

This is the code that handles the AJAX response:

```
var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
                        for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
                            document.getElementsByClassName("inputs")[count].innerHTML =
                                this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('input')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        }

                        // Heating Advance
                        if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('OUTPUT')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ===                                         "checked")  {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT1.checked = true;
                        } 
                        else {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT1.checked = false;
                        } 

                        // Hot Water Advance
                        if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('OUTPUT')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue ===                                         "checked")  {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT2.checked = true;
                        } 
                        else {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT2.checked = false;
                        }
```

I have tried to include the usual examples to set the property of a jQuery checkbox in the 'if' statement but nothing seems to work.

i.e.:

```
if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('OUTPUT')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ===                                         "checked")  {
                            $("#checkbox-1").prop("checked", true);
```

Can I not use the jQuery elements within the HTML body? Im sure this is something embarrassingly obvious that I'm missing.

Here is the checkbox code:

```
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center;">

                <input type="checkbox" name= "OUTPUT1" id="checkbox-1" onclick="GetCheck()" />
                <label for="checkbox-1">Central Heating</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="OUTPUT2" id="checkbox-2" onclick="GetCheck()" />
                <label for="checkbox-2">Hot Water</label>

            </div>
        </form>
```

If I make the checkboxes standard HTML without jQuery styling they work perfectly, is it something to do with the name= and id= attributes?

Any help or a pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Full HTML code here:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    strOUTPUT1 = "";
    strOUTPUT2 = "";

    function GetArduinoIO()
    {
        nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    if (this.responseXML != null) {

                        // XML file received - contains analog values, switch values and LED states
                        var count;

                        // Get Input States (Heating and Hot Water Status)
                        var num_an = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
                        for (count = 0; count < num_an; count++) {
                            document.getElementsByClassName("inputs")[count].innerHTML =
                                this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('input')[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        }

                        // Heating Advance
                        if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('OUTPUT')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ===                                         "checked")  {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT1.checked = true;
                        } 
                        else {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT1.checked = false;
                        } 

                        // Hot Water Advance
                        if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('OUTPUT')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue ===                                         "checked")  {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT2.checked = true;
                        } 
                        else {
                            document.OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT2.checked = false;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // send HTTP GET request with LEDs to switch on/off if any
        request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs" + strOUTPUT1 + strOUTPUT2 + nocache, true);
        request.send(null);
        setTimeout('GetArduinoIO()', 1000);
        strOUTPUT1 = "";
        strOUTPUT2 = "";
    }

    // service LEDs when checkbox checked/unchecked

    function GetCheck()
        {
        if (OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT1.checked) {
            strOUTPUT1 = "&OUTPUT1=1";
        }
        else {
            strOUTPUT1 = "&OUTPUT1=0";
        } 

        if (OUTPUT_form.OUTPUT2.checked) {
            strOUTPUT2 = "&OUTPUT2=1";
        }
        else {
            strOUTPUT2 = "&OUTPUT2=0";
        } 
    }

    </script>
```

And the page body:

```
<body onload="GetArduinoIO()">
    <div data-role="page">         
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">            
    <h1>Drayton Remote</h1>     
    </div>
    <br />

    <div data-role="content">

     <form id="check_OUTPUTS" name="OUTPUT_form">

            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" style="text-align: center;">

                <input type="checkbox" name= "OUTPUT1" id="checkbox-1" onclick="GetCheck()" />
                <label for="checkbox-1">Central Heating</label>

                <input type="checkbox" name="OUTPUT2" id="checkbox-2" onclick="GetCheck()" />
                <label for="checkbox-2">Hot Water</label>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing your `GetCheck()` function in your jQuery. Does it fire off the first code block from your post? From your explanation, it looks like you just want to check or uncheck these boxes based on your XML results, not that you want to fire off an event when the boxes are checked -- is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the HTML code now, yes when the check box is selected it runs the GetCheck() function, this sets the outputs on the arduino web server, this works as intended, however I can't get the HTML code to actually influence the jQuery checkboxes from the AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$('#checkbox-1').attr('checked','checked'); //check
$('#checkbox-1').removeAttr('checked'); //uncheck
```

or in Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox-1').checked = true; //check
document.getElementById('checkbox-1').checked = false; //uncheck
```